# Why onmousedown stops firing when I add an iframe in JSFiddle?

Tags: iframe, jsfiddle, onmousedown

Why does this silly onmousedown example stop working **in the parent** when there is an iframe?

```
document.onmousedown=function(e) {
    console.log("body clicked");
};
```

It works on this page (https://jsfiddle.net/wc74m29n/1)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <!--<iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org" />-->
  <div> lorem ipsum </div>
</div>
```

But fails when I switch to iframe (https://jsfiddle.net/wc74m29n)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org" />
  <!--<div> lorem ipsum </div>-->
</div>
```

Comment: Nested iframe perhaps? JSFiddle puts all your HTML in an iFrame too

Comment: @mplungjan Hmm, right, it could be a limitation with jsfiddle. At least, I couldn't find anything about a nested iframe blocking all onmousedown events in it's parent.

Comment: I even get a `Blocked autofocusing on a <input> element in a cross-origin subframe.`